# Downloaded application

Tags: software-installation, downloads

I've tried a number of time to download a specific application which I now cannot see in the dashboard.

I've done a 'whereis' on the file name to give the the following response:

`/usr/bin/'file_name' /opt/'file_name'/bin/'file_name'`

(where obviously 'file_name is the corresponding app').  May sound like such an elementary question but how do I extract from  the directory.  As stupid as it sounds I can't even get to it to extract and paste in downloads to continue the setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the application?

Comment: And how did you install it?

Comment: if you find it in /usr/bin then apparently you installed it. Try launching it by just typing `'file_name'` in a terminal, where 'file_name' is the name of the un-nameable application...

Comment: @Zanna Absent any clarification from the OP your comment IMHO is the answer. Please write it up as such

Comment: done @ElderGeek but maybe not needed as the post will be closed with one more vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of clarification, at the request of Elder Geek...

> I've done a `whereis` on the file name to give the the following response:

```
/usr/bin/'file_name' /opt/'file_name'/bin/'file_name'
```

It *sounds* like you already installed it, and you should be able to launch it by typing

```
'file_name'
```

(replacing your unwieldy appellation 'file_name' with the actual name of the application). To see which of those three files is being launched, you can do

```
which 'file_name'
```

If nothing happens, and you get no output from `which` it's possible that you put those files there yourself as root, and they are being found by `whereis` even though they are not executable files.

If this is the case, and you want to move any of these files to your Downloads directory to do something with them, use the `mv` command, for example:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/'file_name' ~/Downloads
```

If the application does launch when you type `'file_name'` and it just doesn't have a launcher, then [take a look at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of reply or clarification, I’d not been able to reply until now.  
I appreciate this has now been closed but for the sake of clarification (adding a little variety)…I had indeed been able to move the file name using the ‘sudo mv’ command and launched from there, as stated.  
I shall in future use the application name, I’d not appreciated the extent to which this might obfuscate my question, but again for clarity it was ‘Tor Browser’.
Thank you to those that replied and apologies for any lack in clarification and the ‘unwieldy appellation’.

Comment: haha no worries, that was my attempt at humour... the quotes make it unwieldy because quote marks have special meaning to the shell... did my answer help (you could 'accept' it if you want to) or did you just figure it out?

Comment: Sort of muddled through that one through nothing else other than not being able to access the very help I requested (simple logistical issue on my part) but the information, as ever, is much appreciated and certainly comes in handy.